# How to retrive int data from database to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a code in asp.net page for my progress bar i'm having a back end code to retrieve percentage  my problem is how to retrieve that int value to my java script
here is the code for progress bar is

```
<div class="w3-wow1" style="font-size:x-large">Total Potential</div>

         <div class="w3-padding-32"></div>
          <span class="w3-wow2" style="font-size:x-large">Potential Till Date :</span>
     <button class="w3-btn w3-white w3-round-xlarge" onclick="move1()">Click Here</button> 
        <div class="w3-padding-8"></div>
     <div class="w3-progress-container  w3-round-xlarge" style="height:40px">
     <div id="myBar1" class="w3-progressbar w3-round-xlarge w3-green " style="width:0%">
     <div id="per1" class="w3-center w3-text-white" style="margin-top:10px">0%</div></div>            
     </div>
```

and javascript code for this one is

```
 <script>
     function move1() {
         var elem = document.getElementById("myBar1");

       //var per= int data from database

         var width = 1;
         var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
         function frame() {
             if (width >= 80) { // here in the place of 80 i want to use 'per' variable to assign the progress bar
                 clearInterval(id);
             } else {
                 width++;
                 elem.style.width = width + '%';
                 document.getElementById("per1").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
             }
         }
     }</script>
```

the backend code for this one is

```
    protected void potent()
    {
        string query = "select ( sum(oppfp /100000)* 100.0)AS percentage from opprt";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=leadsp;User ID=sa;Password=123;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        ListItem item = new ListItem();
                        string per = sdr["percentage"].ToString();
                        int percentage = Convert.ToInt32(per);

                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

how to retrieve this data as **int** and pass it to **per** variable in java script

Comment: Create an ajax call via javascript or jquery, make your backend db code to return int and that's it.

Comment: how can i load without using on click function

Answer (score 0):

As Khalid said you can use an ajax call to the server to retrive the update value.
You can use a timer to call the site every second as long as you need it.

A simple example could be:

```
var myTimer = setTimeout(function(){ 
  $.ajax(siteUrl, {
    success: function(data) {
       // do your thing with the downloaded data
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error) {
       alert(error)
    }
  });
, 1000);
```

When you are done you can stop the timer with:

```
clearTimeout(myTimer);
```